# Java Reactor - if/else chaining (filtering)

Tags: java, discord, reactive-programming, reactor, discord4j

I am rewriting my Discord bot from [Discord4J](https://github.com/Discord4J/Discord4J) `v2` to `v3` that's based on Reactor. I am new to reactive programming and Java Reactor in particular. I'd like to implement a commands system with commands of three types:

1. **DM commands** — commands that users send as direct messages to the bot,
2. **public guild commands** — commands that users send in a special channel `#bot-commands` in my Discord server — everyone with some particular role **X** can use these commands, and
3. **admin guild commands** — similar to public, but users must have some role **Y** (which is higher than **X**).

If a user tries to execute some particular command but they haven't got the role required for it, the bot should tell them about that. Otherwise the command should be executed (taking into account the *sender* (message author), the *channel* this command was sent, and the *command* itself (the message)).

I am not sure how to implement this all reactively, and I couldn't find the necessary information on the Discord4J wiki. This is what I currently have:

```java
private final Set<DiscordCommand> discordGuildCommands = new HashSet<>();
private final Set<DiscordCommand> discordDmCommands    = new HashSet<>();

// ...

gateway = DiscordClient.create(discordToken).login().block();

// ...

        gateway.getEventDispatcher()
                .on(MessageCreateEvent.class)
                .filter(event -> !(event.getMessage().getChannel().block() instanceof PrivateChannel))
                .filterWhen(event -> event.getMember().get().hasHigherRoles(Roles.REFLEXBOT_CTRL_SINGLETON))
                .flatMap(event -> Mono.just(event.getMessage().getContent())
                        .flatMap(content -> Flux.fromIterable(discordGuildCommands)
                                .filter(cmd -> content.startsWith(DISCORD_COMMANDS_PREFIX + cmd.getName()))
                                .flatMap(cmd -> cmd.process(event))
                                .next()
                        )
                )
                .subscribe();
```

This code appears to work fine and allows me to process **admin guild commands**, that is, commands sent in my Discord server's text channels by members whose "permission level" (highest role level) is at least one I specified.

But how do I implement the rest of the commands **properly (reactively and nicely)?** I haven't found anything like if/else chaining in Reactor, and I don't really want to duplicate the above code several times with only 1-2 `filter(...)` lines changed.

Comment: moved comment to answer due to formatting

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Discord4J, but I think you should inverse flow and add some settings for your commands.

1. Add hash map [command name => channel/private]
2. Add hash map [command name => minimum role]
3. Add hash map [command name => command]

Then build your flow:

1. Get command from first map (or return error "I dont know that command")
2. Using first map check if command matches with request type (private/channel) (or return error "I dont know that command")
3. Using second map check user role (or return error "Access denied")
4. Get command instance from third map
5. Run the command